# handlebar helper is not working for some code?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I have created two helper for my .hbs file

```
Template.registerHelper("log", function(something) {
  console.log(something);
});
Template.registerHelper("printItems", function(items) {
  var html = "<ul>";
  items.forEach(function(entry) {
    html += "<li>" + entry + "</li>";
  });
  html += "</ul>";
  return html;
});
```

Log is working fine but for printItems i am getting error .

I am trying to print data in table formate but not able to do as i am new with .hbs please help below is the code

```
 <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>S.N</th>
            <th>Team Name</th>
            <th>Dime 1 Score %</th>
            <th>Dime 2 Score %</th>
            <th>Dime 3 Score %</th>
            <th>Dime 4 Score %</th>
            <th>Total Score %</th>
        </tr>
       {{log userData}}
       {{printItems userData}}
        </table>
```

Comment: I think you should post the error you are getting.

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue ...thanks

Comment: Excellent! You should probably post your answer or close your question so that it doesn't linger unresolved.